# How to change annotate distplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I want to change the title, x-title, y-title, and increase the font size of the graph.

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

df_attri = df[df["attrition"] == "Yes"]
g = sns.displot(data=df_attri2, x='TCT_avg', kind="kde", col="attrition", color='cyan', fill=True,alpha=.4, linewidth=4,)

g.fig.set_figwidth(10)
g.fig.set_figheight(5)
mean = df['TCT_avg'].mean()
plt.axvline(mean,linestyle="--", linewidth=4, color='cyan')
g.savefig("plot.png")
```

Comment: you get access to the axes object by `g.fig.axes[0]`, then you can use regular matplotlib methods to modify everything you like, see https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py for an introduction to matplotlib

Comment: @Stef g.set_xlabel('TCTl') gives me error. AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'

Comment: that's why I wrote to use `g.fig.axes[0]`, so it'll be `g.fig.axes[0].set_xlabel('TCTI')`

Comment: Or use `g.ax`. or `g.set`.